# Summing up precipitation in a pandas Dataframe with Datetime index over a chosen timespan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following problem: I have hourly and and 30-min weather data that I sample at 13:00 h on each day for further analysis which is easy for temp and humidity. However the precipitation should be summed up, so that  at 13:00 h sum of the previous 24h is calculated (13:30 the day before to incl. 13:00 the day after). I believed to be successful with the example below, but by double checking I realised that I can´t find a value for the offset argument that does the expected summation. Can anyone help? I am looking for a datetime method to be agnostic of my two different input types (1h vs 30 min. original interval).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generating a sample DataFrame with hourly weather data
np.random.seed(42)
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2023-08-01', end='2023-08-14', freq='H')
data = {
    'Date_Time': date_rng,
    'Temperature_Celsius': np.random.uniform(20, 35, size=len(date_rng)),
    'Precipitation_mm': np.random.uniform(0, 5, size=len(date_rng)),
    'Humidity_Percentage': np.random.uniform(40, 80, size=len(date_rng))
}

weather_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

weather_df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(weather_df['Date_Time'])
weather_df.set_index('Date_Time', inplace=True)
daily_precip = weather_df['Precipitation_mm'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', offset='12H')).sum()
```

Comment: what does 13:00 represents the sum of the previous 24h. mean

Comment: @GoldenLion I edited the question so that I hope it becomes more clear(shorter sentence) which time interval I am trying to calculate here.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a working example (without setting the DateTime index):

```
weather_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

weather_df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(weather_df['Date_Time'])

# Create a helper column with a counter that increases at every record
# with hour equal to 13
weather_df['DAY_COUNT'] = weather_df['Date_Time'].dt.hour.eq(13).cumsum()

# Sum over the groups of the helper column
daily_precip = weather_df.groupby('DAY_COUNT')['Precipitation_mm'].sum()
```

Pay attention that the numbering of the groupby result will always start from 0, no matter the actual day of the first record.

Comment: Hi Alessandro! Thank you, your solution works for well for my hourly data, except I had to change to: weather_df['DAY_COUNT'] = weather_df['Date_Time'].dt.hour.eq(14).cumsum()
 Unfortunately I didn´t manage to adapt your solution to my 30min interval data. The helper column behaves strange.